# Pandas - Compute data from a column to another

Tags: python, pandas

Considering the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_json("""{"week":{"0":1,"1":1,"2":1,"3":1,"4":1,"5":1,"6":2,"7":2,"8":2,"9":2,"10":2,"11":2,"12":3,"13":3,"14":3,"15":3,"16":3,"17":3},"extra_hours":{"0":"01:00:00","1":"00:00:00","2":"01:00:00","3":"01:00:00","4":"00:00:00","5":"01:00:00","6":"01:00:00","7":"01:00:00","8":"01:00:00","9":"01:00:00","10":"00:00:00","11":"01:00:00","12":"01:00:00","13":"02:00:00","14":"01:00:00","15":"02:00:00","16":"00:00:00","17":"00:00:00"},"extra_hours_over":{"0":null,"1":null,"2":null,"3":null,"4":null,"5":null,"6":null,"7":null,"8":null,"9":null,"10":null,"11":null,"12":null,"13":null,"14":null,"15":null,"16":null,"17":null}}""")
df.tail(6)

    week extra_hours  extra_hours_over
12     3    01:00:00               NaN
13     3    02:00:00               NaN
14     3    01:00:00               NaN
15     3    02:00:00               NaN
16     3    00:00:00               NaN
17     3    00:00:00               NaN
```

Now, in every week, the maximum amount of `extra_hours` is 4h, meaning I have to subtract 30min blocks from `extra_hour` column, and fill the `extra_hour_over` column, so that in every week, total sum of `extra_hour` has a maximum of 4h.

So, given the example dataframe, a possible solution (*for week 3*) would be like this:

```
    week  extra_hours  extra_hours_over
12     3     01:00:00          00:00:00
13     3     01:30:00          00:30:00
14     3     00:30:00          00:30:00
15     3     01:00:00          01:00:00
16     3     00:00:00          00:00:00
17     3     00:00:00          00:00:00
```

I would need to aggregate total `extra_hours` per week, check in which days it passes 4h, and then randomly subtract half-hour chunks.

What would be the easiest/most direct way to achieve this?

Comment: Why are you randomly subtracting?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you are randomly subtracting, I'm not sure a pandas dataframe is what you want to use

Comment: One way might be to use `df.groupby('week').apply(a_custom_function)` with `a_custom_function` a function performing the random sustraction.

Comment: So we need to iterate row by row, and while the total time is above 4, decrease the value of this row by 30mins, check if the condition if met. If not, decrease it another 30 mins, until that row is equal to 0. Then move to the next row. Pitifully I can't get time to code it right now, but that is how I would solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here goes one attempt for what you seem to be asking. The idea is simple, although the code fairly verbose:

1) Create some helper variables (minutes, extra_minutes, total for the week)

2) Loop through a temporary dataset that will contain only while sum is > 240 minutes.

3) In the loop, use `random.choice` to select a time to remove 30 min from.

4) Apply the changes to minutes and extra minutes

The code:

```py
df = pd.read_json("""{"week":{"0":1,"1":1,"2":1,"3":1,"4":1,"5":1,"6":2,"7":2,"8":2,"9":2,"10":2,"11":2,"12":3,"13":3,"14":3,"15":3,"16":3,"17":3},"extra_hours":{"0":"01:00:00","1":"00:00:00","2":"01:00:00","3":"01:00:00","4":"00:00:00","5":"01:00:00","6":"01:00:00","7":"01:00:00","8":"01:00:00","9":"01:00:00","10":"00:00:00","11":"01:00:00","12":"01:00:00","13":"02:00:00","14":"01:00:00","15":"02:00:00","16":"00:00:00","17":"00:00:00"},"extra_hours_over":{"0":null,"1":null,"2":null,"3":null,"4":null,"5":null,"6":null,"7":null,"8":null,"9":null,"10":null,"11":null,"12":null,"13":null,"14":null,"15":null,"16":null,"17":null}}""")

df['minutes'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['extra_hours']).hour * 60 + pd.DatetimeIndex(df['extra_hours']).minute
df['extra_minutes'] = 0

df['tot_time'] =  df.groupby('week')['minutes'].transform('sum')

while not df[df['tot_time'] > 240].empty:
    mask = df[(df['minutes']>=30)&(df['tot_time']>240)].groupby('week').apply(lambda x: np.random.choice(x.index)).values
    df.loc[mask,'minutes'] -= 30
    df.loc[mask,'extra_minutes'] += 30

    df['tot_time'] =  df.groupby('week')['minutes'].transform('sum')

df['extra_hours_over'] = df['extra_minutes'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timedelta(minutes=x))
df['extra_hours'] = df['minutes'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timedelta(minutes=x))
df.drop(['minutes','extra_minutes'], axis=1).tail(6)

Out[1]:
    week    extra_hours     extra_hours_over    tot_time
12  3       00:30:00        00:30:00             240
13  3       01:30:00        00:30:00             240
14  3       00:30:00        00:30:00             240
15  3       01:30:00        00:30:00             240
16  3       00:00:00        00:00:00             240
17  3       00:00:00        00:00:00             240
```

**Note**: Because I am using `np.random.choice`, the same observation can be picked twice, which will make that observation change by a chunk of more than 30 min.